# Getting data out of an Object ; JAVA

Tags: java, object, arraylist

I would like to get the information of an Object.

I call a Webservice form a client, and get the response.

`Object result = envelope.getResponse();`

The Webservice returns an `ArrayList<String>`

How do I access the data ?

The Webservice fills the ArrayList like this, the information are parsed from a XML file.

```
tempDataStorage.add(getValue("ITEM_NAME", element));
tempDataStorage.add(getValue("VALUE", element));
tempDataStorage.add(getValue("CURRENCY", element));
tempDataStorage.add(getValue("DESCRIPTION", element));

return tempDataStorage;
```

To be more specific:

How can I get the `ITEM_NAME, VALUE, CURRENCY, DESCRIPTION` into a String variables, on the Client side?

Please tell me, if you need me to provide more information.

Thank you!

Comment: did you tried to cast your `result` to `ArrayList<String>`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cast your `result`  to `ArrayList<String>`  and use [ArrayList#get(int)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#get%28int%29)  method.

like

```
ArrayList<String> resultList = (ArrayList<String>) result;
```

Then you know the story right ??  :)

Remember `index` starts from `0`

Comment: Thank you very very much! Yeah, sure. I don't know why it didn't come into my mind, to simply cast it ...

Answer (score 2):

Cast to an ArrayList.

```
((ArrayList)object).get(itemindex);
```

That should work.

Answer (score 2):

Casting to ArrayList can give you the solution

```
((ArrayList)object).get(i) // i is the index
```